# Continuously subscribing and unsubscribing from Observable for BLE scans

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rxandroidble

I'd like to implement a feature where a BLE scan is activated for 10 seconds, then breaks for 10 seconds, and repeats while the view is active.

I'm using `RxAndroidBle` which wraps the Android BLE APIs for reactivity. I have a method `scanForRange(getConnectAddress());` which uses an `Observable<RxBleScanResult>` and some filters and a map applied to return a simple `Observable<Integer>`. To start the scan, this observable must simply be subscribed to, and then unsubscribed to stop the scan.

My first thought was to use `Observable.interval()` as shown below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mRangeScanSubscription = Observable.interval(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> call(Long aLong) {
                    return scanForRange(getConnectAddress());
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() error");
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Integer integer) {
                    Toast.makeText(DeviceDetailActivity.this, "Range: " + integer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

I would then unsubscribe from that Subscription in my `onPause()`. Now this does not work, as once the first interval is emitted, the scan is subscribed to and will continuously emit results (instead of the inteded start/stop every 10 seconds).

What would be the best way to implement this feature then? I assume I could probably hack it together with a mix of Observables and Handlers, but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `TakeUntil` and `RepeatWhen` operators

```
        mRangeScanSubscription = scanForRange(getConnectAddress())
            .takeUntil(Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) //emits items for 10 seconds
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) //resubscribes after 10 seconds
            ...
```

Comment: This seems to be working as expected. Thanks! I'll mark your answer as correct.